# Correlate list of items after drag and drop event

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a list that contains **days of the week** and one that contains **aliments**. I've created a *Meal Planner* in which you can drag and drop the aliments below each day of the week(as you can see in the picture) but i don't know how to correlate the two of them. In my database i have a table for the *Meal Planner* with **idAliment** and **idWeekDay** but i don't know how i can save the correct values for, let's say -week day : monday ; aliments:bagels, biscuits-

**here is the picture!**

[image]

**The controller code**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveMealPlanner(MealPlannerModel model) 
{
    try 
    {
        var dbMealPlanner = new MealPlanner();
        dbMealPlanner.Name = model.MealPlannerName;
        dbMealPlanner.IdMember = model.MemberId;
        dbMealPlanner.MealPlannerAliments = new List < MealPlannerAliment > ();

        foreach(var item in model.Aliments) 
        {
            var mealPlannerAliment = new MealPlannerAliment();
            mealPlannerAliment.IdAliment = item;
            dbMealPlanner.MealPlannerAliments.Add(mealPlannerAliment);
        }

        db.MealPlanners.Add(dbMealPlanner);
        db.SaveChanges();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Json(ex.ToString());
    }
    return Json("Meal planner saved!");
}
```

Comment: Your image you refer to is missing.  Also please post code that you have already and what you have tried

Comment: Sorry! I posted the picture and the code i wrote in my controller